# Selection outline in search results (from GUI) on a sheet that is set to xlNoSelection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where I set `Sheet.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection`.

Reasons I need `xlNoSelection` to remain:

- The user must be able to both sort and filter the table that resides in the sheet using the table's GUI.
- The user must not be able to in any way alter (including adding or removing) the contents of any cell inside the table. Sorting the table does not count against this criteria even though Excel considers the sort process as "changing cell contents".
- The user must not be able to insert/remove columns or rows.

`xlNoSelection` in conjunction with locking the sheet (while the cells' `Locked`-property is false) is the only solution I have found that solves this, and my setup is operational as is. The only thing lacking is the selection outline during "binocular search" from the Home ribbon.

I'm observing that the search function does in fact select the cell (and the cell contents is in part visible in the formula bar), but there is no selection outline around the selected cell (I guess this is a feature of `xlNoSelection`).

**My question: is there a way I can get the selection outline back while retaining `xlNoSelection`? The outline is only necessary during the search, but it doesn't matter if it's permanently active (or not) as long as no manual selections can be made.**

I thought about using a manual selection highlight feature using `Worksheet_Change`, but it would be clunky since the user can't make any selections on their own - meaning the last-most search result will remain highlighted after the user has exited the search.

Any suggestion (including moving away from `xlNoSelection`) is welcomed as long as my bulletpoint criteria at the top of the post aren't violated.

Comment: When you select  "Protect Sheet", you are presented with a list of individual permissions to allow or disallow. Bullet point #1 is covered by enabling the "Sort" and "Use AutoFilter" permissions. Bullet point #2 is covered implicitly by Protecting the Sheet - no edits can be made as long as you don't leave any specific cells unlocked. Bullet point #3 is also covered by the protection. If you want the cells to be "selectable", for example to allow copy/paste, you can ensure that the "Select locked cells" and "Select unlocked cells" permissions are checked.

Comment: Is there some other criteria you are looking for besides your 3 bullet points?

Comment: No other criteria, no. But: bullet point #1 and #2 cannot be achieved simultaneously in the way you describe, because (1) "Sort" is disallowed on locked cells, and (2) leaving the cells unlocked (so that sort may be used) leaves them open to editing. Setting `xlNoSelection` bypasses this leaving the cells unlocked while also not letting the user select any of them (and thereby blocking any edits).